# Uploading images in the database via WCF

Tags: c#, sql, linq, wcf, visual-studio

I want to upload an image in the database via WCF. I'm bulding a WP 8 app that will upload image in the database and then show it on the user's profile page. Didn't find anything related to WP except for [this tutorial](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Uploading-and-downloading-images-from-WCF-in-Silverlight.aspx). I'm trying to follow it, but get errors. Here is my service implementation:

```
public bool Upload(Stuff picture)
    {
        Stuff stPic = new Stuff();
        stPic.stuffName fileStream = null; //error 1
        stPic.stuffPhoto writer = null; 
        string filePath;

        try
        {
            filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(".") +
                       ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PictureUploadDirectory"] +
                       picture.stuffName; //error 2,3

            if (picture.stuffName != string.Empty)
            {
                fileStream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Create);//error 4,5
                writer = new BinaryWriter(fileStream); //error 6
                writer.Write(picture.stuffPhoto);
            }

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (fileStream != null)
                fileStream.Close();
            if (writer != null)
                writer.Close();
        }
    }
```

Errors:

> 1) The type or namespace name 'stPic' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> 2)The name 'HttpContext' does not exist in the current context.
>
> 3) The name 'ConfigurationManager' does not exist in the current context.
>
> 4) The name 'File' does not exist in the current context
>
> 5) The name > 'FileMode' does not exist in the current context
>
> 6) The type or > namespace name 'BinaryWriter' could not be found
>    (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> 7) DBML1005: Mapping between DbType 'VarBinary(MAX)' and Type 
>   'System.Data.Linq.Binary' in Column 'stuffPhoto' of Type 'Stuff' is not supported.

**EDIT:** Added using statements so errors 2,3,4,5,6 are gone.

```
using System.Web;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
```

Changed the code as it was in the tutorial (error 1 is gone).

```
FileStream fileStream = null;
BinaryWriter writer = null;
```

But this line of code is highlighted `writer.Write(picture.stuffPhoto);` and the errors are: `1) The best overloaded method match for 'System.IO.BinaryWriter.Write(string)' has some invalid arguments. 2) Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Data.Linq.Binary' to 'string'`.

Also I tried to change the type of the `stuffPhoto` field in the database to `image` and created `LINQ to SQL Classes` again. But got same type of error: `DBML1005: Mapping between DbType 'Image' and Type 'System.Data.Linq.Binary' in Column 'stuffPhoto' of Type 'Stuff' is not supported.`

**EDIT:** I fixed 7th error by opening dbml file in xml editor and replacing `System.Data.Linq.Binary` type to `System.Byte[]`. As a result those two errors above are gone as well. So now web service compiles without errors.

Comment: This syntax is not valid: `stPic.stuffName fileStream = null; stPic.stuffPhoto writer = null`. What are you trying to achieve there?

Comment: @GertArnold, I thought that in that way I would define members of my `Stuff` class to use them afterwards in the code. But I was confused as didn't understand what that line is doing. Now I see it doesn't make sense, so I will write these two lines like in the tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
stPic.stuffName fileStream = null; //error 1
```

Unless you have a nested type called `stuffName` defined in the class `stPic` which inherits from `FileStream`, (which seems unlikely!) this code doesn't make sense as you seem to be trying to set a property called `stuffName` and a variable called `fileStream` at the same time. The tutorial you link to creates a `FileStream` with `FileStream fileStream = null;`, why not just do that?

```
 stPic.stuffPhoto writer = null;
```

I would expect that to give the same error as above.

For errors 3, 4, 5 and 6, add references in your project to `System.Web`, `System.Configuration`, and `System.IO`. In order to access the `HttpContext` you will need to add this to your web.config file:

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true">
```

You haven't listed the code which gives error 7.

Comment: There is no code for error 7. I defined `stuffPhoto` (member of `Stuff` class) as `VarBinary(MAX)` type and I think it is not supported by the `LINQ to SQL Classes`. But I read that I should define this type in the database to convert my images in the byte array. Those tutorials were not using `LINQ to SQL Classes`, so I don't know what type is right in my case.